# I got this error, ld: library not found for -lerl_interface

Tags: ejabberd

[image]

I am following this https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/ and got the error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejabberd 20.04 supports Erlang/OTP from 19.3 up to 22.3. The new Erlang 23 is not supported yet, see https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3282

Solution? By now, use an older Erlang version.

Comment: Thank you, I had figured it out. Yes, I had changed to Erlang 19.3

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-lerl_interface`, it is no longer required.